# Disable mapping of `Man`

Tags: key-bindings, default-settings

I have this mapping in my `~/.config/nvim/mappings.vim` (it's included with `source` from the `init.vim` file):

```
noremap <S-k> 5gk
vnoremap <S-k> 5gk
```

I went through a part of the vim manuals and found this entry: `:h find-manpage`. I was always wondering why the help page popped, if I pressed `Shift-k` and now there's the reason! But why does the default `K` binding still opens the manual page although I used `noremap`?

Comment: Shift-k is K. I don’t completely know why you’re mapping isn’t taking precedence, but you could just remap K directly. (Aside: I like K’s behavior, so I don’t recommend getting rid of it! keywordprg can be quite nice, and it’s a shame that it’s so difficult to make some languages work with it.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm sorry for answering very late. Could you please write your suggestion `just remap K directly` as an answer so I can tick this question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a mapping like this, I would just remap `K` directly:

```
noremap K 5gk
```

(Personally, I like `K`'s `keywordprg` usage, and it's a shame so many languages are hard to use it with. So I recommend not doing this, but YMMV.)